# pdftk : no file generated

Tags: php, pdftk

I asked my host to install PDFTK on my webhosting account. It's installed because I can see the response when I try :

```
    exec("/usr/bin/pdftk --version",$o,$r);
```

However, every real command I try doesn't output any file. Here are few examples :

```
    exec("/usr/bin/pdftk /var/www/vhosts/mtlmf.com/httpdocs/test.pdf /var/www/vhosts/mtlmf.com/httpdocs/test2.pdf cat output /var/www/vhosts/mtlmf.com/httpdocs/newfile.pdf",$o,$r);

    exec("/usr/bin/pdftk $pdf_template_path fill_form $xfdf_file_path output $pdf_name flatten");
```

All files stated does exist (I verified with file_exists than the path was valid).

I tried many things on that, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: When you said you tried `/usr/bin/pdftk --version` did you try it from `exec("/usr/bin/pdftk --version",$o,$r)` ?

Comment: Yes, I ran it with exec( ) and $o/$r gave me the correct response. I do not have access to command line – I edited the initial post, sorry about this confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permission issue! 0777 to the folder and it appears now ...